# How to discover what file in the dev/ directory is related to the SD card reader of my laptop?

Tags: drivers, sd-card, devices, card-reader, dmesg

how can I discover what file inside **dev/** directory is related to my SD card reader of my laptop?

I thought that I could execute the following operations:

1) Remove the SD card from the reader

2) Insert it again into the reader

3) Open the **dmesg** log and search in the lasts records

But this is not possible for me because my Ubuntu is installed on a virtual machine and when I remove and put it again the SD card the system crash

What can I do to discover it?

EDIT 1: executing sudo fdisk -l I obtain this output

```
Disco /dev/sdb: 7948 MB, 7948206080 byte
255 testine, 63 settori/tracce, 966 cilindri, totale 15523840 settori
Unità = settori di 1 * 512 = 512 byte
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Identificativo disco: 0x00000000

Dispositivo Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1            8192    15518789     7755299    b  W95 FAT32

Disk /dev/sda: 42.9 GB, 42949672960 bytes
255 testine, 63 settori/tracce, 5221 cilindri, totale 83886080 settori
Unità = settori di 1 * 512 = 512 byte
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Identificativo disco: 0x000ba73e

Dispositivo Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048    77080575    38539264   83  Linux
/dev/sda2        77082622    83884031     3400705    5  Esteso
/dev/sda5        77082624    83884031     3400704   82  Linux swap / Solaris
andrea@andrea-virtual-machine:~$
```

Tnx
Andrea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend:

`sudo fdisk -l`

Comment: I have edited the original post, can you help me to understand the output? the SD card is 8 GB, so is it /dev/sdb1 ?

Comment: yep, /dev/sdb is your card /dev/sdb1 is the first and only partition on that card.